# Can 'return' rewrites exist within a vhost with other hostnames?

Tags: nginx

We're using Nginx as a reverse proxy to pass traffic into our infrastructure which responds to `foo.com` and `*.foo.com` host headers internally. We have an http server configured whose sole job it is to redirect these to the https server, but also accumulated rules for other things like `*.www.foo.com` and `www.*.foo.com` which is rewritten to strip the `www.`. [Old people think that `www` *must* be in *every* URL *somewhere*] Its config block looks something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name
        ~^([\w-]+\.)?foo\.com$
        ~^([\w-]+\.)?www\.foo\.com$
        ~^www\.([\w+-]\.)?foo\.com$
    return 301 https://$1foo.com$request_uri;
}
```

However, in order to accomodate the coming "HTTPS-only" world I need to add rewrites of non-standard hostnames into the https server block as well. I am hoping that the rewrite and non-rewrite config can live in the same block in order to keep the config concise.

I've tried the below config, but it is not issuing the redirect and is passing incorrect www.bar.foo.com host headers into the backend application.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name ~^www\.([\w-]+\.)?foo\.com$;
    return 301 https://$1foo.com$request_uri;

    server_name foo.com *.foo.com;
    location ... {
        proxy_pass ...
    }
    ...
}
```

It also generates the below warning, which I find to be odd:

```
nginx: [warn] server name "https://$1foo.com$request_uri" has suspicious symbols
```

Comment: The warning is because of the typo, where you forgot the semicolon.

Comment: Hah. The one in my question is a transcription error, but the one in my 443 config was the problem. However now the 301 triggers for all requests regardless of if it matches that pattern. Really all I want is to not duplicate the SSL config across 2 different server blocks. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Argh. Even a second `server` block doesn't work because the regex has a lower precedence than the `*.foo.com` wildcard which catches it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what I was missing [aside from the semicolon] was the [`if`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) directive for the rewrite module. `return` is a blunt instrument that's good for following `server_name` specifications [and other things I'm sure], `rewrite` is good for rewriting the path portion of a URI, but carving out a specific regex of a hostname that's already covered by a wildcard requires the use of an `if` statement like below.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name foo.com *.foo.com;

    if ( $host ~ ^www\.([\w-]+\.)?foo\.com$ ) {
        return 301 https://$1foo.com$request_uri;
    }

    location ... {
        proxy_pass ...
    }
    ...
}
```